# Getting arrangable bars out of bad drum timing in pro tools

Tags: pro-tools

In front of me are 28 drum parts recorded with no click. At least i know they're 4/4. 
I want to arrange them into a song, but of course nothing fits,... no click.

A lot of youtube videos on fixing drum timing use elastic audio with beat detective or manual identify to get drum recordings back in timing, but i can't get to their results.

In the next picture, i used manual identify on each 2nd snare hit of an 8/4 'blast beat'.

[image]

Anything i do with elastic audio at this point will create horrible distortions, i'm assuming its because of the big differences between each beat.

Is there any better way to get arrangeable bars out of this material that doesn't involve fixing the timing of each individual beat?

Maybe there is a way to average the warp so that the total length of 4 bars will fit into actual 4 bars, but the warp within that region is minimized?

Suggestions for any other tool to do this is appreciated as well.